# How to update/reload a particular value in a web page only if it has changed? (using html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload, updates

I have created a web page using HTML and JavaScript (CSS is also used). I have set a refresh interval of 10 seconds. I don't want to refresh the entire page. I need to refresh/reload only those values which have changed. If no values are changed, no refresh should occur. I searched a lot but couldn't find out anything that would help me.

```
    title: {
        text: "Title Name",
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: "Sub Title Name",
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Name",
        data: [ "23" ],
    }]
```

For Example, If "Title Name" is changed, only "Title Name" should be updated. Other values should not be reloaded.
Every 'x' seconds, it should check for changes and if any changes, that particular value should be updated without affecting rest of the values.

Any suggestion/sample code would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:
I take values from the XML files. It will look like this.

```
    title: {
    text: Title_Name,
},
subtitle: {
    text: Sub_Title_Name,
},
series: [{
    name: Name,
    data: [ Value ],
}]
```

Where Title_Name, Sub_Title_Name, Name and Value are variables which store the values from XML files.

Comment: What's the point? If you fill in something with the same value it already has, there's no difference.

Comment: Maybe you would like to take a look at [ajax](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: @Barmar I agree there is no difference. But it saves the reloading time.

Comment: @Isaias Can i use Ajax in the same web page or should I create a new one? I don't know Ajax but I don't mind implementing it if that is the only solution to this..

Comment: Aren't you already using AJAX? Where are the new values coming from if not AJAX?

Comment: Save the old values in an object. When you get the new values, go through the properties of the old and new objects, and update the ones that are different.

Comment: Values are stored in XML files.

Comment: Of course you could use it on the same page, it's only javascript. Also consider using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you're going this way. Check Makrand's answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Since you have included jQuery tag i would like to suggest jQuery AJAX functionality for it.

> 1. All it requires you to specify the data params (can be json too)
> 2. Do the internal / query related operations in your php or other server side code.
> 3. Control is returned back in success msg to the AJAX wherein you can modify your changed values.

Sample code :

```
//Using jQuery library
$.ajax({
  url : "your-server-side-logic", //I'm assuming you would be creating your refresh logic for text in here
  type : "post",
  dataType : 'json',
  data : {
    name : "a-name",
    data : 23 
  }, success : function(success_record) {
    //Here comes your "refresh-specific-content-only-part".
  }
});
```